# Pandas map data frames using partial strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames (`df`, `df_ref`) where the latter contains a key and value that should be mapped to `df`.

The challenge is that I cannot directly map the respective columns in `df` and `df_ref` as the strings contained in the reference are only partially overlapping with the strings contained in `df`.

`df` looks like this:

```
    path            filesize    ctime
0   /pathA/stuff    171.0       Tue Dec 17 01:50:17 CET 2013
1   /pathB/stuff2   162.0       Tue Dec 17 01:50:17 CET 2013
2   /pathA/stuff2   156.0       Tue Dec 17 01:50:17 CET 2013
```

`df_ref` looks like this:

```
    path                            owner
0   /stuff/longer/pathA/stuff       foo
1   /stuff/longer/bla/pathB/stuff2  bar
2   /stuff/stuff/pathA/stuff2/temp  baz
```

I want to align the two data frames on the column `path` and add the `owner` from `df_ref` to `df`.

My current train of thought yielded (partial code to illustrate the workflow):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pattern = r'^(?:\/[^\/]+){2}(\/([^\/]+\/?[^\/]+\/?){2,3})'
df_ref["partial_path"] = df_ref["path"].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)[0]


for row, data in df.iterrows():

    data["owner"] = np.where(data["path"].str.contains(df_ref["partial_path"]), 
        df_ref["owner"], "unknown")
```

I am looking for an approach that would avoid looping through any of the data frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `.apply`,

```
>>> df['owner'] = df['path'].apply(lambda path: df_ref.loc[df_ref['path'].str.contains(path), 'owner'].iloc[0])
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> df
            path  filesize                         ctime owner
0   /pathA/stuff     171.0  Tue Dec 17 01:50:17 CET 2013   foo
1  /pathB/stuff2     162.0  Tue Dec 17 01:50:17 CET 2013   bar
2  /pathA/stuff2     156.0  Tue Dec 17 01:50:17 CET 2013   baz
```